# How to know if NSOperation operation is finished?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperation

I need to set a string from my NSOperation, but how can I know if the operation is finished? Cause it is not hitting the breakpoint that I've set, or I am not calling my NSOperation properly? If yes, how should I call my operation?

Here's my code

```
- (void)operationDidFinish:(MJOperation *)operation
{
NSString *strng  = [MJUtilities decodedStringFromXMLData:operation.receivedData];

mainString = [NSString stringWithFormat:mainString, strng];

}
```

Now I need to get the value of mainString

Comment: The `stringWithFormat` line doesn't make sense.  Where do you post the operation?  How does the operation call `operationDidFinish`?

Comment: Edited my post. That's the thing, I don't know how I am going to call operationDidFinish. But I need to get the mainString once I've clicked in my a cell in my tableView

Comment: Have you set up KVO observing for your operation's `finished` property somewhere?

Comment: Is that the line with addObserver:self? I think I removed it cause I think I don't need to use it anymore

Comment: Yes, you would probably  have a line something like [operation addObserver:self forKeyPath:"finished" ...] but I don't know what this `MJOperation` is, so that class may have a different approach

Comment: Can you give me a snippet on how should I do it? Given the code above, I have this in my MJOperation @protocol MJOperationDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)operationDidBegin:(MJOperation *)operation;
- (void)operationDidFinish:(MJOperation *)operation;
- (void)operationDidFail:(MJOperation *)operation;

@end;

Comment: Right, so it seems that this `MJOperation` class is trying to simplify things for you.  I have no knowledge of this framework.  Where did you get it from? Have you set the `delegate` of your `MJOperation` instance?

Comment: I am modifying a existing project and have no idea of this framework too.  In the MJOperation yes, but in my class i don't think so

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a NSOperation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37851114/how-to-call-a-nsoperation)

Answer (score 3):

Set the `completionBlock` property on your `NSOperation`. When the operation finishes, the `completionBlock` is called.

See the `NSOperation` documentation for more info: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSOperation/completionBlock

Try something like this:

```objc
__block NSString *mainString;

...

myOperation.completionBlock = ^{
    NSString *strng  = [MJUtilities decodedStringFromXMLData:myOperation.receivedData];
    mainString = [NSString stringWithFormat:mainString, strng];
    // here you should do something with mainString
};
```